# Limit the output of XSLT element to 2000 characters

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to limit the output of an XSLT element to 2000 chars. The element has many IF conditions and depending upon which conditions are true the sub-elements are displayed. I cannot use concat() function as the variable is re-initialized in every IF block. I cannot use substring() as there are many sub-elements and i want the concatenation of all sub-elements to be 2000 chars. I am currently working on javascript option but without much luck. I am a newbie to XSLT so any help much appreciated.

Thanks,
Clayton

Comment: It seems that you aren't too-sure about your exact requirements. In particular, what do you mean by "i want the concatenation of all sub-elements to be 2000 chars" -- are you going to remove complete subtrees or do you want the removal/ truncation of text nodes only? You must be aware that an XML document is not just a string -- instead it is a tree of nodes. You are talking here about the string representation of such tree. when deleting characters from the string representation of an XML document it is very easy to end-up with a string that isn't representation of a well-formed XML document.

Comment: Sorry for that ambiguous statement. The requirement is to concatenate all sub-elements(which are text nodes only) and extract the first 2000 chars. It also means to reject any sub-elements that are beyond 2000 chars.

Comment: @C D, Still very vague. Please, edit the question and provide a concrete small example with limit , say 40 characters -- we need to see the original output and the exact wanted output.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this approach work. Do the transform as you require it to work but leave the result in a variable rather than in the output doc. Then put a substring of this into the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:variable name="normalResult">
    <!-- Put your basic transform code here -->
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <TrimmedResult>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($normalResult, 1, 2000)"/>
    </TrimmedResult>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect Kevan ... thanks a ton, I I used the following, 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"; version="1.0">
 
<xsl:variable name="normalResult"> 
<!-- Put your basic transform code here --> 
</xsl:variable> 

<element>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($normalResult, 1, 2000)"/> 
</element>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that you are going to be able to do this in pure XSLT in a nice way. Instead, I would recommend writing a different program that runs after your XSLT transformation, that truncates any long elements in the resulting XML to 2000 characters.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the quick reply. Do you think that i incorporate the logic in the same xsl file or create a new file altogether? There are other elements as well whose output can exceed 2000 chars.

Comment: Depending on your exact requirements, it may be easiest to do this in a *second* XSLT transformation that is run after your first one. You could have that second transformation truncate all text nodes to a maximum of 2000 characters without worrying about which nodes they are.

Answer (score 0):

Both Greg and Kevan have given you examples of the right design here: do the first transformation without truncation, then do the truncation in a second transformation.

The only question mark over this is performance. If the first transformation is going to generate 50Mb of output and you only want the first 50K, this isn't an efficient approach. If at all possible, rewrite the requirements to express them in terms of the size of the input rather than the size of the output. If you can't do that, and if the two-phase approach is too wasteful, then the only solution I can think of is to inject some stateful extension functions that monitor how much output is being produced and allow you to ask whether the limit has been exceeded. Details will depend on your choice of processor.